# WP Plugin with Upgrade option

Tags: plugin-development, upgrade, premium

I'm working on a Wordpress Plugin and I'm looking for a way to include a free version and a premium version in one plugin.

I do not want to check "if(isPremium){} else{}" every view lines of codes, instead I'd like to download some additional files and replace one or two old once as soon as a premium license is activated. Can anyone give me a hint on how I could realize this functionality?

Best regards
Macuser

Answer (score 1):

If you want your plugin being hosted on [WordPress.org Plugin Repository](https://wordpress.org/plugins/), you cannot combine Free and Premium version, in one plugin.

You have to maintain two versions, Lite, hosted on WordPress.org, and Premium, hosted on your website.

Plugins hosted on WordPress.org cannot make any remote requests to your website ( aka "calling home" ), therefore, you will not be able to maintain your customers, their licences, payments, and downloads.